sequelize-auto conf overwritten
I'm trying to use sequelize-auto to create models for my postgres db. I'm following the docs and have this config.js:
const path = require('path');
const output = path.join(__dirname, "./models2");
const options = { directory: output, caseFile: 'l', caseModel: 'p', caseProp: 'c', lang: 'ts', useDefine: false, singularize: true, spaces: true, indentation: 2 };

// postgres
const postgres = {
  dbname: 'mydb',
  user: 'postgres',
  pass: 'mypw',
  options: {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: 'my-instance.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 5432,
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    }
  },
  autoOptions: { dialect: 'postgres', ...options }
};

module.exports = postgres;

and I then run:
npx sequelize-auto -c config.js
But I get this output / error:
{
  dbname: 'mydb',
  user: 'postgres',
  pass: 'mypw',
  options: {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: 'myinstance.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 5432,
    dialectOptions: { ssl: [Object] }
  },
  autoOptions: {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    directory: '/home/ec2-user/myapp/models2',
    caseFile: 'l',
    caseModel: 'p',
    caseProp: 'c',
    lang: 'ts',
    useDefine: false,
    singularize: true,
    spaces: true,
    indentation: 2
  },
  directory: '/home/ec2-user/myapp/models',
  additional: {},
  dialect: 'mysql',
  port: 3306,
  host: 'localhost',
  database: undefined,
  storage: undefined,
  tables: null,
  skipTables: null,
  skipFields: null,
  pkSuffixes: null,
  schema: undefined,
  lang: 'es5',
  caseModel: 'o',
  caseFile: 'o',
  caseProp: 'o',
  noAlias: false,
  noInitModels: false,
  noWrite: false,
  views: false,
  singularize: false,
  username: undefined,
  useDefine: false,
  indentation: 2,
  noIndexes: false
}
ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/home/ec2-user/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:92:17)

It seems like there is some default configuration that's being added and make my command fail.
Nowhere in my code I've set port 3306 or dialect mysql.
